# react router render app and login

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this route:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="login">
            <IndexRoute component={LoginPage}/>
        </Route>
        <Route onEnter={requireAuth}>
            <IndexRoute component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="accounts">
                <IndexRoute component={AccountPage}/>
                <Route path="add" component={AccountAdd} />
                <Route path="detail/:id" component={AccountDetail} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="contacts">
                <Route path="detail/:id" component={ContactPage}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="transmissors">
                <Route path="detail/:id" component={TransmissorPage}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="attends" component={AttendancePage} />
            <Route path="reports" component={ReportPage} />
            <Route path="configs" component={ConfigurationPage} />
       </Route>
    </Route>
```

Inside my App component I want to have a conditional to render the login page and the App page.

I do not know how to do this conditional at my App.

Here is my App code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.children.type.name);
    }

    render() {

        const loginRender = this.props.children.type.name == "LoginPage";
        const appRender = this.props.children.type.name != "LoginPage";

        return (


            {loginRender(
                <div className="app-container">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            )}

            {appRender(
                <div className="app-container">
                    <Header />
                    <Sidebar />
                    <Middle app={this.props.children}/>
                </div>
            )}



        );
    }
}

export default App
```

I do not know if use this.props.children.type.name to get the loginpage is best way or a good pratice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using react-router onEnter method you need to check if user is authenticated before actually mounting App component and redirect user to "/login" if she is not authenticated. You do not need to render LoginPage inside App component. For example:

```
//I use here token authentication, but it can be adopted easily in your case
function redirect(nextState, replace) {
   if (auth.loggedIn()) {
     replace('app');
   } else {
     replace('login');
   }
}

function redirectHome(nextState, replace) {
  if (auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace('app');
  }
}

function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace('login');
  }
}

<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="login" component={Login} onEnter={redirectHome}/>
    <Route path="app" component={Layout} onEnter={requireAuth}>
      <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
      <Route path="accounts" component={Accounts}/>
      <Route path="settings" component={Settings}/>
    </Route>
  <Route path="*" onEnter={redirect}/>
</Router>
```

in this example login page is rendered in Login component

Comment: I am trying here and tell you if I got

Comment: I am not getting login and go to app page, can I edit my question for you try help me?

Comment: try to console.log(auth.loggedIn()) in each function and see what it returns. also try to remove cb attribute and cb() from the functions

Comment: and you can of course remove legacy requireAuth function because you use yours

Comment: I edited the code accordingly to my comments. just check if auth.loggedIn() returns true and false appropriately

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onEnter` method inside your route with react-router

Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js)

You can see too the [EnterHook](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#enterhook)